# Entity Framework Core - can't seem to use Include

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I've been doing BI project management work for several years and coming back into some web app dev work now. I am building an asp.net core app and using EF core. Lazy loading isn't enabled on EF Core, which is fine. I think I want to use .Include to load a related object.

So if you have

```
 public class Customer {
       public int CustomerId { get; set; }
       public Address { get; set; }
 } 

 public ViewResult List()
 {
       CustomerListViewModel customersListViewModel = new CustomerListViewModel();
       customersListViewModel.Customers = _customerRepository.Customers.??? // Include does not resolve...

        return View(customersListViewModel);
    }
```

I am trying to return an IEnumbable of Customers that eagerly loads the Address as well. The other answers suggest I should be able to use .Include() but that doesn't seem to be an available method for me.

Comment: .Include() is available in EF Core

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't seem to be an available method for me*? You need reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` assembly and `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in the source code file.

Comment: And please don't mix EF with unknown Repository pattern implementations. The `Include` is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Okay I added "using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" to the CustomRepository and then did appDbContext.Customers.Include("Address"); and that seems to work.

Comment: You may also want to use the lambda overload of Include. so .Include(a => a.Address). This has the added benefit of compile time errors over run time errors if there is any issue with accessign the table you reference

Comment: I have taken your suggestion, thank you @Oliver.